# Where in Wordpress does a typical blog title get rendered (.php file and method name please)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to change the title of my blog (link usually at top left corner of site) from `<h1>` to `<h2>`. (for example, for this website it's the stackoverflow link at the top left corner)

I need to know where the .php file which renders the title is located.

Right now, I can see that the title is being rendered within a do_atomic, but i'm not sure what that means or how to go deeper into it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in [wordpress root]/wp-content/themes/[current theme name]/header.php or [wordpress root]/wp-content/themes/[current theme name]/functions.php.

Comment: Very close to finding it, i've traced it down to one last method where I need to know the location from. I know this method is it because 'h1' is commented and declared near it. Where can I find: hybrid_site_title(); ?? Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind!! Found it after finally learning some bash commands. $ find .  | xargs grep "hybrid_site_title(" Thank you so much Connor though!!